# Can we say that $\{g_n\}$ is a subsequence of $\{f_n^j\}$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis

We suppose that $\{f_n^1\}$, $\{f_n^2\}$, $\{f_n^3\}$,...$\{f_n^k\}$,....are the sequences such that $\{f_n^j\}$ is a subsequence of $\{f_n^{j-1}\}$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$.

Take $g_n=f_n^{n^2}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Can we say that $\{g_n\}$ is a subsequence of $\{f_n^j\}$ for all $j\in\mathbb{N}$?

Comment: Do I correctly understand from your definition, that $\{f_n^{m}\}$ is subsequence of $\{f_n^{l}\}$, where $m<l$?

Comment: @zkutch see please my edit

Comment: aha, you changed in to reverse - now $\{f_n^{m}\}$ is subsequence of $\{f_n^{l}\}$ where $m>l$ . But now about your question: you want $\{f_n^{n^2}\}$ compare to $\{f_n^{j}\}$ for all $j \in \mathbb{N} $ or to some $j$ related to $n^2$?

Comment: @zkutch  we know that $\{f_n^n\}$ (diagonal)  is a subsequence of $\{f_n^j\} $ for all $ j$. My problem : can we say that $\{f_n^{n^2}\}$  is a subsequence of $\{f_n^j\} $ for all $ j$.

Comment: Sorry, but I do not see that property for diagonal, as you had subsequence depending on upper index: let's consider infinite 2d matrix with all $0$-s and $1$-s only on diagonal. Suppose our sequences are columns. Then your property holds, but ${f_{n}^{n}}=1$ is not subsequence for any column.